# Using Docker and Python, how to access csv file created in volume?

Tags: python, docker

### Edit

Added suggestions from daudnadeem.

1. Created folder in the directory with my Dockerfile called `temp_folder`.
2. Updated the last line of the python file to be `df.to_csv('/temp_folder/temp.csv')`.
3. Ran the docker build and then new run command `docker run -v temp_folder:/temp_folder alexd/myapp .`.

---

I have a very simple Python example using Docker. The code runs fine, but I can't figure out how to access the CSV file created by the Python code. I have created a volume in Docker and used `docker inspect` to try to access the CSV file but I'm unsure of the syntax and can't find an example online that makes sense to me.

#### Python Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import os

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df.to_csv('temp.csv')
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.1

RUN mkdir -p /var/docker-example

WORKDIR /var/docker-example

COPY ./ /var/docker-example

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT python /var/docker-example/main.py
```

#### Docker commands

```
$ docker build -t alexf/myapp -f ./Dockerfile .

$ docker volume create temp-vol

$ docker run -v temp-vol alexf/myapp .

$ docker inspect -f temp.csv temp-vol
temp.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "temp.csv" lives on the ephemeral docker image. So in order for you to access it outside of the docker image, the best thing for you to do is expose a volume.

In the directory where you have your Dockerfile, make a folder called "this_folder"

Then when you run your image, mount that volume to the folder within your container `docker run -v this_folder:/this_folder <image-name>`

Then change this code to:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import os

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df.to_csv('/this_folder/temp.csv')
```

"this_folder" is now a "volume" which is mutually accessible by your docker container and the host machine. So outside of your docker container, if you `ls /this_folder` you should see `temp.csv` lives there now.

If you don't want to mount a volume, you could upload the file somewhere, and download it later. But in a local env, just mount the folder and use it to share files between your container and your local machine.

#### Edit

when stuff is not going as planned with docker, you may want to access it interactively. That means 'ssh'ing into your docker container'

You do that with: `docker run -it pandas_example /bin/bash`

When I logged in, I saw the file 'temp.csv' is being made in the same folder as the main.py

Now for you to solve the issue further is up to you. You need to move the 'temp.csv' file into the directory which is shared with your local machine.

```
FROM python:3.7.1

RUN pip3 install pandas

COPY test.py /my_working_folder/

CMD python3 /my_working_folder/test.py
```

For a quick fix add

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("mv temp.csv /temp_folder/", shell=True)
```

to the end of main.py. But this is not recommended.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that docker volumes don't always live in the same location. See here https://timonweb.com/posts/getting-path-and-accessing-persistent-volumes-in-docker-for-mac/

Comment: :/ that is super confusing. If you specify absolute paths, I can assure you the data will be there.

Comment: @medley56 as you can see, Alex F did `docker create volume...` where as I created a folder and mounted that directly. maybe if you use `docker volume create` that creates the folder on it's own, and hence, it won't always be in the correct place.

Comment: So I followed your directions but I'm still not seeing any files in `this_folder`. I've updated my code above to show your directions.

Comment: @AlexF Check my edit. I will post a neater solution tomorrow from the office.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make things simple if your only goal is to understand how volumes work and where to find the file on the host created by Python code inside the container.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.7.1

RUN mkdir -p /var/docker-example

WORKDIR /var/docker-example

COPY . /var/docker-example

ENTRYPOINT python /var/docker-example/main.py
```

**main.py** - will create /tmp/temp.txt inside the container with `hi` inside

```
with open('/tmp/temp.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hi')
```

**Docker commands (run inside the project folder):**

Build image:
`docker build -t alexf/myapp .`

Use named volumed `vol` which is mapped to `/tmp` folder inside the container:

Run container: `docker run -d -v vol:/tmp alexf/myapp`

Inspect the volume:`docker inspect vol
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-11-05T22:07:02+02:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/vol/_data",
        "Name": "vol",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]`

**Bash commands run on the docker host**

```
sudo ls /var/lib/docker/volumes/vol/_data
temp.txt

sudo cat /var/lib/docker/volumes/vol/_data/temp.txt
hi
```

You can use also bind mounts and anonymous volumes to achieve the same result.

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)