# Docker volume is not sharing files

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I believe that creating a docker volume (as explained by another user) is a solution for sharing files between my docker container and home machine. I have created a volume, and can see that files are being saves within the correct filename within my docker container, but these are not saving in to my home directory.

My docker command is below:

```
docker run -it --rm --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 --name=ContainerName -v Images:/Images ImageName
```

I am trying to save into a file called 'Images', and have broadly followed the guide given at [Using Docker and Python, how to access csv file created in volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58715205/using-docker-and-python-how-to-access-csv-file-created-in-volume)

I can see that, within my docker container, the photo 'Mask.png' is being saved:

[image: Console command ls demonstrating Mask.png is within file Images]

However, within the home folder 'Images' there is no Mask.png:

[image: There is no file in the folder 'Images' in my home directory.]

I should add, this folder Images is stored in the same directory as my Dockerfile, which was expressly mentioned in the stack overflow thread mentioned above.

Many thanks for your help. (Clearly, based on my question history) I'm quite new to docker so this might be a really basic question, but I couldn't really find much on here or google that would help me solve my issue.

Comment: You are looking for a bind mount. `-v ./Images:/Images`. You also need to create the directory on your host first.

Comment: Right, let me have a go :)

Edit: That works! Thanks very much! (Though just out of interest, I don't think relative directories work ie. ./Images, I had to write the full directory)

Comment: Ok. They work in docker-compose.yml files. I never really get a hang of all the little differences in how they work.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by super, the solution was to include the full directory. I therefore actually used the command:

```
docker run -it --rm --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 --name=ContainerName -v /home/username/code/Kaggle2/Images:/Images ImageName
```